# ¿Cómo duplicar la tabla generada de HTML usando valores del array Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

No sé si no estoy insertando bien el array, pero no me arroja los valores en las tablas.

PD: necesito 4 tablas, no sé cómo llamar los array.

Pregunta más especifica: ¿cómo mandar a llamar o traerme datos específicos del array desde HTML?

Teniendo este formato en HTML:

[adjunto trabajo en Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/87z9tkxc/)

Comment: ¿Has logrado solucionar esto? Si es así agradeceríamos que publicaras cómo lo hiciste (yo mismo te daría un voto) o bien que cerraras la pregunta. Gracias.

Comment: @OscarGarcia no  pude

Comment: @OscarGarcia la verdad lo deje hice otro , pero  lo retomare no me gusta quedarme a medias

Comment: En el código de fiddle veo formato de plantillas de Vue.js. ¿Quieres mantener Vue.js o hacerlo con javascript puro (vanilla javascript)?

Comment: @OscarGarcia con vanilla

Comment: Ya estoy de vuelta por aquí. Antes de nada, no te olvides que en [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/341933/18608) marcaste como correcta la respuesta de otra persona. PD: La pregunta está un poco enrevesada. ¿Sólo quieres clonar la tabla con los datos del array? Luego hablas de tener cuatro tablas... no entiendo mucho al final qué deseas hacer.

Comment: Desisto, me está costando realizar un ejemplo para reproducir el problema. Necesitaría un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), pero en ese código hay etiquetas desemparejadas, el JSON sólo muestra datos de un único encuentro. No entiendo cuando dices que necesitas cuatro tablas, etc. Si no aclaras un poco mejor tu problema y, sobre todo si ya lo has solucionado, creo que no merecerá la pena el tiempo que invierta en hacerlo.