# Pagina se cuelga en Validacion del Login

Tags: php, mysql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Pues yendo al grano, tengo un problema con una pagina que subi, el problema es que al iniciar sesion o "loguearse" y l hacer la validacion , la pagina se queda colgada en la validacion y no redirecciona la pagina, probe todo en local y funciona, solo que al subirla se cuelga ahi.
agradeceria si me pudieran orientar como solucionarlo gracias.

Lo unico que hice fue reemplazar,http://localhost:8082  por la pagina del host donde esta alojada
la base de datos si esta conectada, ya que hice un echo en la validacion para ver que me arrojara algo y si, solo que como mencione en la validacion se cuelga

Anexo codigo de la validacion

```
introducir el código aquí
```

```
 <?php
session_start();
?>

<?php

include 'conexion.php';

$conexion = new mysqli($host_db, $user_db, $pass_db, $db_name);

if ($conexion->connect_error) {
 die("La conexion falló: " . $conexion->connect_error);
}

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username = '$username'";


$result = $conexion->query($sql);


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {     }


$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
 // if (password_verify($password, $row['password'])) { 
if ($password==$row['password']) { 


    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['id'] =$row['id'];
    $_SESSION['name'] =$row['name'];
    $_SESSION['start'] = time();
    $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (5 * 60);


    header('Location: http://localhost:8082/Andor%20Shop/productos.php');//redirecciona a la pagina del usuario

 } else { 
   echo "Username o Password estan incorrectos.";

   echo "<br><a href='login.html'>Volver a Intentarlo</a>";
 }
 mysqli_close($conexion); 
 ?>
```

Conexion

```
<?php
$host_db = "localhost";
 $user_db = "id12893306_andorstore";
 $pass_db = "123456";
 $db_name = "id12893306_tienda";
 $tbl_name = "clientes";
?>
```

Comment: No te esta generando ningún archivo error_log ? quizás no este activado, busca como activarlo en tu hosting, con eso podrás saber mas detalles.

Comment: ¿Has comprobado si en el inspector de red se ven redirecciones en bucle? En `productos.php`, ¿cómo compruebas que la sesión es válida? ¿Se "cuelga? o da página en blanco? En ese caso, podría estar generándose un error y deberías mirar el log de error del servidor.

Comment: Y otra cosa, ¿hay realmente un espacio antes de la apertura de PHP en ` <?php` o ha sido un error al copiar y pegar? Si envías cabeceras (en enviar un espacio en blanco al navegador) te generará una advertencia de cabeceras enviadas al log de error.

Comment: en error log no arroja nada y la pagina se queda en blanco no redirecciona

Comment: no se conserva la session.

Comment: ¿Quieres que se mantenga la sesión entre el hosting externo (la de **000webhostapp**) y **localhost:8082**?

Comment: no ,  localhost es mi  pagina local, ya subi mi pagina a ese host

Comment: Recuerda nombrar con un @ delante a la persona a la que te diriges para que nos llegue una notificación. En caso contrario si no pasamos de nuevo por esta pregunta no sabemos que nos has contestado. ¿Podemos conocer la URL para ver si está devolviendo un error 500 o un error de bucle de redirecciones? ¿Sabes usar el inspector de red? ¿Prefieres que usemos el chat para comunicarnos?

Comment: @OscarGarcia si disculpa, https://handymanutt.000webhostapp.com/Andor%20Shop/

Comment: user TonyM  Pass   scar123

Comment: Vale, es lo que yo pensaba. Ese espacio en blanco te está matando el funcionamiento del envío de las cabeceras.

Comment: @OscarGarcia yaclo quite y anda igual

Comment: Haber esperado a la redacción de mi respuesta. No solo es el espacio antes del `<?php`, también son las líneas entre el `?>` y el siguiente `<?php` que hay entre medias. También cuenta lo que contenga el archivo `conexion.php`.

Comment: @OscarGarcia


<?php
$host_db = "localhost";
 $user_db = "id12893306_andorstore";
 $pass_db = "123456";
 $db_name = "id12893306_tienda";
 $tbl_name = "clientes";
 $db = new mysqli($host_db, $user_db, $pass_db, $db_name);
 if ($db->connect_error) {
     die("No hay Conexion con la base de datos: " . $db->connect_error);
 } 
?>

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta pulsando en el enlace [editar (aquí mismo)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/341858/edit) y agregas al final el código. Aquí se pierde el contenido y el formato.

Comment: @OscarGarcia ya subi conexion, ahora ya no queda blanco, pero no loguea xD eso ya es bueno creo.

Comment: @OscarGarcia ya quedo, solo que el stylo de bootstrap no me sale

Comment: [Acabo de mover los comentarios al chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106116/discussion-between-oscargarcia-and-yisus-spec). Por favor, continuemos por allí.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

estoy convencido que es por el header

prueba poner un exit depues del header

```
header(".....");
exit;
```

o prueba con un die

```
  header(".....");
  die();
```

por cierto esta linea de codigo no te estara dndo algun tipo de problema ???

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {     }
```

le estas indicando que si hay mas de un registro que haga algo pero no haces nada.....

Comment: este if tienes razon no sirve , y si pongo el exit al header si me la pone en blanco , lo intente en mi local, y la pone en blanco, algo que acabo de descubrir es que la session no se guarda por decirlo asi , cuando llega  a producto.php no la detecta

ya quite este 

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {     }

Comment: @OscarGarcia muchas gracias ya quedo

Comment: De nada, pero esta no es mi respuesta, es la de la otra persona ;) te equivocaste al marcarla como correcta :D

Comment: yo tambien he votado a la otra respuesta que no es la mia, ya que era otro problema que estaba viendo, pero no estaba seguro al 100%, ya que los headers siempre se deben colocar antes que cualquier etiqueta  que vaya a estar dentro de un <body>, lo se por experiencia propia, hace años me daban muchos dolores de cabeza...

Answer (score 2):

El problema que estás sufriendo es debido a que tienes un espacio en blanco y un par de líneas que provocan el envío de cabeceras al navegador, impidiendo que `session_start()` envíe las suyas o las de `header(..)`.

Has de comprobar que el archivo `conexion.php` tampoco tenga espacios ni líneas extras. Si solo contiene código PHP quítale el cierre de PHP (`?>`) ya que es normal que tras el cierre de PHP se incluyan retornos del carro o espacios que también provocan el envío de cabeceras.

Edito: Ahora que has compartido el código de `conexion.php`, te recomiendo dejarlo así:

```
<?php
$host_db = "localhost";
 $user_db = "id12893306_andorstore";
 $pass_db = "123456";
 $db_name = "id12893306_tienda";
 $tbl_name = "clientes";
/* No es necesario (ni recomendable) cerrar PHP cuando solo hay código */
```

Aquí tienes un ejemplo del código de `checklogin.php` corregido:

```
<?php
/* Lo primero que ponemos, sin espacios en blanco antes del "< ?php" */
session_start();
/* Aquí quito el cierre de PHP y apertura, porque envía también esas líneas */

require_once 'conexion.php';

$conexion = new mysqli($host_db, $user_db, $pass_db, $db_name);

if ($conexion->connect_error) {
  /* Usa htmlspecialchars para que los caracteres especiales se muestren bien */
  die('La conexion falló: '. htmlspecialchars($conexion->connect_error));
}
/* ¡¡¡OJO en la inyección SQL!!! */
$username = $conexion->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = $conexion->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

/* Ahora es seguro concatenar al SQL la variable */
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username = '$username'";

$result = $conexion->query($sql);

/* Si vas a usar sólo los índices alfanuméricos, usa "assoc" y no "array" */
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
if ($password == $row['password']) { 
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['id'] =$row['id'];
    $_SESSION['name'] =$row['name'];
    $_SESSION['start'] = time();
    $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (5 * 60);

    /* Hacemos la página relocalizable sin tocar código */
    $destino = $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ? 'https' : 'http';
    $destino .= '://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $destino .= ':'. $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'];
    $destino .= '/Andor%20Shop/productos.php';

    /* Ahora la cabecera se enviará correctamente */
    header('Location: '. $destino);
    /* Finalizamos la ejecución del script */
    die();
 } else {
   echo "Username o Password estan incorrectos.";
   echo "<br><a href='login.html'>Volver a Intentarlo</a>";
 }
 /* No es necesario (ni recomendable) cerrar PHP en scripts con solo código */
```

Además, he de advertirte que el código sufre de los [graves problemas de seguridad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpKIhF7naSY) asociados a la [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL) que debe solucionarse con consultas preparadas o usando [`mysqli::real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysqli.real-escape-string) tal y como te he mostrado en el código.

Comment: ya subi el archino nuevo yno :/

Comment: ¿Y revisaste el contenido de `conexion.php`? Ahora sí aparece **Username o Password estan incorrectos.
Volver a Intentarlo**, antes no aparecía eso, se quedaba la página en blanco, así que algo ha mejorado el código :)

Comment: totalmente de acuerdo con OScarGarcia , utiliza sentencias sql parametrizadas, no utilices este tipo de sentencias "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE ...:" , esto ha quedado obsoleto en programacion...